# Conflicting dependency when updating ADT Plugin

Tags: android, eclipse

I've just updated new things from the Android SDK manager in eclipse and now I get this error when starting eclipse:

[image: 1]

Check for Updates doesn't find nothing. So I've looked for new ADT Plugin this way:

- Select Help > Install New Software.
- Click Add, in the top-right corner.
- In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

- Done.

It finds the next updates:

[image: 2]

But when trying to update, this is What I'm getting:

[image: 3]

And I get this same error for the 6 update packages.

Is there a way to solve this, or should I delete eclipse and install the new bundle?

Comment: I fixed it downloading the last ADT update from the android website,

Comment: @blackbelt the workspace remains the same if I do that?

Comment: if you do not delete it, still you can make a backup copy

Comment: @blackbelt could you provide the link? And what's better, to download eclipse and independently install the ADT plugin, or to have the package which contains all this

Comment: [there you are,](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). I use the adt bundle.. In the past I used eclipse with the plug in. I do think, it does not much difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying to find an easy way (non deleting actual environment) to solve this problem without luck, what has worked for me is the solution proposed by blackbelt.

I've had to delete old entire directory adt-bundle-... and install the downloaded new one.

Answer (score 1):

This happened with me as well.
What I did was I Deleted the .android folder(Which was at "**C:\Users\PC1.android**" and after deleting that, the adt-bundle folder.

I extract the ADT-Bundle zip again and It works for me/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, just uninstall all old android developer tools plugin(android DDMS,Development Tools, hierarchy viewer,NDT, Trace View Open GL ES) and update.That worked for me.
*What I found is that when updating eclipse plugin yout should first delete old plugin and then install the new version otherwise, conflicting dependency error will show up.*

Comment: How do you uninstall just those ones? Can yo do it from eclipse?

Comment: Just got to Help>About Eclipse SDK>Installation details>Installed software n select what u want to uninstall

Comment: Well, I think you'll have the eclipse software and the ADT plugin installed independently. I have the ADT bundle so when trying you solution, now I can't restart eclipse... So I'll need to see if I can restart it some way or I'll need delete it entirely and reinstall it

Comment: Thanks but I finally deleted old version and installed the new one

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error as you. I did the Help>Install new software too, then I selected the developer tools, I can clicked next, but I could not click finish. I have been searching an answer for this for some time now, and everybody says the same thing although it never seems to *work*.

Try something different that actually WORKS.

I fixed it in 5 minutes:

1-Make sure you still have the original zip file (me it's "adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321")

2-Copy the contents of the zip where you want it to be

3-It's like 1.30 GB (I think), so depending on your computer it could take a few minutes

4-Once it's copied, open it.

5-Go in the eclipse folder, then open the eclipse application (you can even pin it to the taskbar if you use it a lot)

I had this problem a few times, and this always works for me.