# Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency. Eclipse error for ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.

```
 Software being installed: Android Hierarchy Viewer 23.0.2.1259578      
 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.feature.group 23.0.2.1259578)
```

I have read all the previous answers bt didnt help !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24673235/conflicting-dependency-when-updating-adt-plugin/24681962#24681962

Comment: @user3639423 please try with wf9a5m75's answer. it work every time for me. I am getting this type of issue in many computer and this trick always resolve that issue.

Answer (score 12):

I had that as well, but I didn't want to reinstall my Eclipse.
So I uninstalled the ADT bundle plugins (from **Eclipse->About Eclipse-> Installation Details -> Android DDMS (and others) -> [Uninstall]**), then **restart** the eclipse.

After that, **install the ADT plugin** again.

This worked without any issues.

Comment: I am using mac..But doing like this corrupts the ADT...I had to remove the ADT and install again..and I am stuck with the conflict bug

Comment: for me this removed everything ;/

Answer (score 3):

I had that as well, I found I had to remove Eclipse and then get the latest Eclipse and ADT bundle from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html. This then works without any issues.

Comment: they have removed the ADT from that link

Comment: Google have now released Android Studio 1.0 Stable, and they have said all developers should now switch over to Android Studio as ADT is no longer in active development.

Comment: Yes they have but we can't quickly switch over to android studio...as the folder structure and build tools are different now..

Comment: The following link has links to the latest ADT http://stackoverflow.com/q/25197353/3857586

Answer (score 1):

For all those who still want to download eclipse with adt here is the download link https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip (this is 32 bit)

For 64 bit https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip

Google has removed these links from their site as they are saying that Android Studio is now the official IDE but these download links are working fine