# Unable to find android NDK builder r9 for mac

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build

I have a need to build my code using Android NDK builder r9.

But I don't have windows with me only mac.

I was able to find it for windows

http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9-windows-x86.zip

http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9-windows-x86_64.zip

But I couldn't find it for mac.

Note:
I have searched on stackoverflow and google nothing was helpful

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this one. Just show on the main downloads page from Android developers that they refer to Mac OS X as Darwin.

For `NDK r9`:

> http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9-darwin-x86_64.tar.bz2

**Update**

Answering the comment of [Venky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3857586/venky).

For `NDK r10b` there're two packages:

> http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk64-r10b-darwin-x86_64.tar.bz2
>   http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk32-r10b-darwin-x86_64.tar.bz2

**Update 2**

For the newest **NDK** version (Currently `NDK r10d` at the time of writing this update) the download link changed from `tar.bz2` to `.bin` extension

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I am unable to download ndk r10b builder....Here is the URL https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10b-darwin-x86_64.bin Can you help me ?

Comment: NDK r10 builder for both 32 and 64 bit has 64 bit only.Plz refer  http://i.stack.imgur.com/eUQez.png

Comment: @Shajo I never said that they were 32 or 64, I said that there where 2 packages available at that moment.

Answer (score 5):

- [R9 builder for 64 bit mac](http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9-darwin-x86_64.tar.bz2)
- [R9 Builder for 32 bit mac](http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9-darwin-x86.tar.bz2)

Comment: eventhough the answer is late one upvote for giving the link to 32 bit

Comment: I am unable to download ndk r10b builder....Here is the URL dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10b-darwin-x86_64.bin Can you help me ?